# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user cod

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.; database=sample; integrated security=SSPI");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from city", con);
con.Open();

SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
GridView1.DataBind();

con.Close();
```

I want to create a connection to SQL Server 2016 from my .net application, but I get this error when I execute the code:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL

Comment: most likely ur sql server instance is not installed or there or it's no running

Comment: Do you have sql server installed? Can you connect to it with SQL Server Management Studio? If yes, what is the instance name you see in SSMS?

Comment: This error means you can't connect to the instance of SQL Server. It's either not accessible, not running, or not even installed.